# How to remove columns for real in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have a large system, and table schema updates quite offtenly, I noticed that after times of removing and recreating new cloumn, limitation "tables can have at most 1600 columns" is shown, but still there are few columns in information_schema.columns.

I've tried vacuum full analyze, still not working, any way to avoid this limitation?

```
DO $$
declare tbname varchar(1024);
BEGIN 
   FOR i IN 1..1599 LOOP
            tbname := 'alter table vacuum_test add column test' || CAST(i AS varchar(8)) ||' int';
            
      EXECUTE tbname;
   END LOOP;
END $$;

alter table vacuum_test drop column test1;

VACUUM FULL ANALYZE  vacuum_test;

alter table vacuum_test add column test1 int;
```

result:

```
alter table vacuum_test add column test1 int
> ERROR:  tables can have at most 1600 columns

> 时间: 0.054s
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Yes, Thanks. I'll also consider dynamic filed with key-value store plan

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think this is worth an answer - I wasn't aware of that either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately `vacuum full` does not remove dropped columns from the table (i.e. entries that have `attisdropped = true` in `pg_attribute). I would have expected that, but apparently this does not happen.

The only way to get rid of the hidden columns is to create a brand new table and copy the data to the new table.

Something along the lines:

```
create table new_table (like old_table including all);

insert into new_table
select *
from old_table;
```

Then drop the old table and rename the new one to the old name. Constraint and index names will be named differently, so you might want to rename them as well.

**You will have the re-create all foreign keys** (incoming and outgoing) manually as they are not included when using `CREATE TABLE (LIKE ...)`.

Another option is to use [pg_repack](https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack/) which does this transparently [in the background](https://reorg.github.io/pg_repack/#full-table-repacks) without locking the table.

Comment: According to this: https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack/issues/101#issuecomment-1290529343 it is incorrect that pg_repack is able to do this.